# Is there a way to identify tokens in a string while also going by longest substring?

Tags: java, regex, token, lexer

I'm trying to figure out how to properly identify tokens from an input file and return what type it is supposed to be while using a delimiter for white-spaces and new lines.
The four types that the lexer is supposed to identify are:

```
Identifiers = ([a-z] | [A-Z])([a-z] | [A-Z] | [0-9])* 
Numbers = [0-9]+ 
Punctuation = \+ | \- | \* | / | \( | \) | := | ;
Keywords = if | then | else | endif | while | do | endwhile | skip
```

For example, if the file has as a line that says:

```
tcu else i34 2983 ( + +eqdQ
```

it should tokenize and print out:

```
identifier: tcu
keyword: else
identifier: i34
number: 2983
punctuation: (
punctuation: +
punctuation: +
identifier: eqdQ
```

I can't figure out how to get the lexer to go by longest substring for a case in which two different types are right beside each other.

This is what I have for an attempt:

```
//start
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

//input file//
File file = new File("input.txt");
//output file//
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");

//instance variables
String sortedOutput = "";
String current = "";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
String delimiter = "\\s+ | \\s*| \\s |\\n|$ |\\b\\B|\\r|\\B\\b|\\t";
String[] analyze;
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

//lines get read here from the .txt file
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
sortedOutput = sortedOutput.concat(scan.nextLine() + System.lineSeparator());
}
//lines are tokenized here
analyze = sortedOutput.split(delimiter);

//first line is printed here through a separate reader
current = read.readLine();
System.out.println("Current Line: " + current + System.lineSeparator());
writer.write("Current Line: " + current + System.lineSeparator() +"\n");

//string matching starts here
for(String a: analyze) 
    {
        //matches identifiers if it doesn't match with a keyword
        if(a.matches(patternAlpha))
        {
            if(a.matches(one))
            {
                System.out.println("Keyword: " + a);
                writer.write("Keyword: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
            }
            else if(a.matches(two))
            {
                System.out.println("Keyword: " + a);
                writer.write("Keyword: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
            }
            else if(a.matches(three))
            {
                System.out.println("Keyword: " + a);
                writer.write("Keyword: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
            }
            else if(a.matches(four))
            {
                System.out.println("Keyword: " + a);
                writer.write("Keyword: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
            }
            else if(a.matches(five))
            {
                System.out.println("Keyword: " + a);
                writer.write("Keyword: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
            }
            else if(a.matches(six))
            {
                System.out.println("Keyword: " + a);
                writer.write("Keyword: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
            }
            else if(a.matches(seven))
            {
                System.out.println("Keyword: " + a);
                writer.write("Keyword: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
            }
            else if(a.matches(eight))
            {
                System.out.println("Keyword: " + a);
                writer.write("Keyword: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Identifier: " + a);
                writer.write("Identifier: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
        //number check
        else if(a.matches(patternNumber))
        {
            System.out.println("Number: " + a);
            writer.write("Number: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        //punctuation check
        else if(a.matches(patternPunctuation))
        {
            System.out.println("Punctuation: " + a);
            writer.write("Punctuation: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        //this special case here updates the current line with the next line
        else if(a.matches(nihil)) 
        {
            System.out.println();
            current = read.readLine();
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Line: " + current + System.lineSeparator());
            writer.write("\nCurrent Line: " + current + System.lineSeparator() + "\n");
        }
        //everything not listed in regex is read as an error
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading: " + a);
            writer.write("Error reading: "+ a + System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
//everything closes here to avoid errors
scan.close();
read.close();
writer.close();
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pure regex is probably not the best approach here.  You need to write a parser.

Comment: @Tim To recognise *tokens*? That’s the canonical use-case of regular languages. Regular expressions are generally sufficient for that, and definitely are in OP’s case.

Answer (score 1):

This can definitely be done without a parser since tokens that are input to a parser can almost always be defined by a regular language (the Unix tools Lex and Flex have been doing this for years. See [Flex (lexical analyser generator)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)). I did not want to take the time to hand-translate some Python code that I had that did this very thing into Java, but I took a few minutes to modify it for your example. I did make a few changes that I think are appropriate. As input to a parser, you would typically want to treat the `(`,  `)`, and `;` characters as distinct tokens. You would also want to treat each each reserved word as a distinct token class rather than lumping them together as KEYWORDS (or the singular KEYWORD as I have done).

**Methodology**

1. Define your tokens using regular expressions with named capture groups. Make sure you have one for whitespace and comments (if your language defines comments).
2. Include an ERROR token that will match any single character (using `'.'` for the regex) to ensure that `find()` always returns a match until the input is exhausted. This ERROR regex must be the last alternate pattern and if it is matched, it represents an unrecognizable token.
3. Place these is a list making sure that the regular expression(s) for all of your reserved words precedes your regular expression for an identifier.
4. Create a single regular expression from Step 3 by "joining" the items in your list with the "|" operator.
5. Search for the next match. If the actual match found is whitespace or a comment and these tokens have no semantic meaning to the parser, continue matching. If it is the ERROR token, return that to the parser, but do not return successive error tokens. When the input is exhausted, return an end-of-file token.

**Quick Java Implementation**

This version is structured so that `next` method can be called to return `Token` object. Also, it is usually more convenient for the the token type to be represented by an integer because it will ultimately be used to index into parse tables:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Lexer {

    public static class Token
    {
        public int tokenNumber;
        public String tokenValue;

        public Token(int tokenNumber, String tokenValue)
        {
            this.tokenNumber = tokenNumber;
            this.tokenValue = tokenValue;
        }
    }

    public static int WHITESPACE = 1; // group 1
    public static int PUNCTUATION = 2; // group 2 etc.
    public static int LPAREN = 3;
    public static int RPAREN = 4;
    public static int KEYWORD = 5;
    public static int IDENTIFIER = 6;
    public static int NUMBER = 7;
    public static int SEMICOLON = 8;
    public static int ERROR = 9;
    public static int EOF = 10;

    Matcher m;
    String text;
    boolean skipError;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lexer lexer = new Lexer("tcu else i34 !!!! 2983 ( + +eqdQ!!!!"); // With some error characters "!" thrown in the middle and at the end
        for(;;) {
            Token token = lexer.next();
            System.out.println(token.tokenNumber + ": " + token.tokenValue);
            if (token.tokenNumber == EOF)
                break;
        }
    }

    public Lexer(String text)
    {

        String _WHITESPACE = "(\\s+)";
        String _PUNCTUATION = "((?:[+*/-]|:=))";
        String _LPAREN = "(\\()";
        String _RPAREN = "(\\))";
        String _KEYWORD = "(if|then|else|endif|while|do|endwhile|skip)";
        String _IDENTIFIER = "([a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*)";
        String _NUMBER = "([0-9)]+)";
        String _SEMICOLON = "(;)";
        String _ERROR = "(.)"; // must be last and able to capture one character

        String regex = String.join("|", _WHITESPACE, _PUNCTUATION, _LPAREN, _RPAREN, _KEYWORD, _IDENTIFIER, _NUMBER, _SEMICOLON, _ERROR);

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        this.text = text;
        m = p.matcher(this.text);
        skipError = false;
    }

    public Token next()
    {
        Token token = null;
        for(;;) {
            if (!m.find())
                return new Token(EOF, "<EOF>");
            for (int tokenNumber = 1; tokenNumber <= 9; tokenNumber++) {
                String tokenValue = m.group(tokenNumber);
                if (tokenValue != null) {
                    token = new Token(tokenNumber, tokenValue);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (token.tokenNumber == ERROR) {
                if (!skipError) {
                    skipError = true; // we don't want successive errors
                    return token;
                }
            }
            else {
                skipError = false;
                if (token.tokenNumber != WHITESPACE)
                    return token;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
6: tcu
5: else
6: i34
9: !
7: 2983
3: (
2: +
2: +
6: eqdQ
9: !
10: <EOF>
```

[Java Demo](https://ideone.com/3Yn0Pd)